# UML diagram - how to show FINAL

Tags: java, uml

How would I display the field

```
private static final int DAMAGE = 3;
```

in the UML Diagram?

Should it be shown as: `- DAMAGE : 3 : int` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an UML representation of a Java project, it should be sufficient to write underlined caps, like…

[image: A constant in a UML class diagram]

**Note** that this representation uses a Java convention (constants written in capitals) to highlight it as `final` instead of a UML annotation, which would be kind of more straight-forward UML, but is too long for my purposes.

Comment: *underline is for static type*, search for static in https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-reference.html

Answer (score 18):

You show it like this.

[image]

`Private` is symbolized by a minus. The `static` attribute is shown by an underline. The initial value is shown by `= <value>`. Since I learned that `final` denotes a constant, you will apply the `isConst` property which is shown as `{readOnly}`.

See also p. 111 of the UML spec:

> ```
> <property> ::= [<visibility>] [‘/’] <name> [‘:’ <prop-type>] [‘[‘ <multiplicity-range> ‘]’] [‘=’ <default>] [‘{‘ <prop-modifier > [‘,’ <prop-modifier >]* ’}’]
> ```
>
> [ details omitted ]

---

No longer relevant in this context, but leaving it anyway:

Re. @granier's comment about tagged values: Indeed UML 2.5 does no longer really use tagged values. There are only 3 mentions of it:

- mainly p. 205

  > Just like a Class, a Stereotype may have Properties, which have traditionally been referred to as Tag Definitions. When a Stereotype is applied to a model element, the values of the Properties have traditionally been referred to as *tagged values*.

So *tagged value* is an "ancient" term and should further be called *stereotype property*.

Comment: @Kilian, tagged value still exists ? I thought it was used in previous version of the specification, and that now it is stereotype properties. Another point, EA allows to create stereotype easily but I guess that to you use a stereotype you have to define a profile including this stereotype then to load the profile in the project.

Comment: @granier You have a point here, I was not aware of. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: I stil think that you can invent stereotypes at wish (like there is no rule for naming classes). It's a meta-classification. But then again, the spec says there must be a profile for a stereotype  p. 278 /profile : Profile [1..1]{}

Comment: @granier I started a discussion: http://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,38955.msg241373.html#msg241373

Comment: @Kilian, my goal is not to get point but to improve the answer when it make sense ;) . There are "a lot's" of points where EA does not follow the norm exactly ... For example, Modifier cited for the answer about pure virtual ...

Comment: "have a point" means "you have a good/interesting argument", not getting SO-points :-) And thanks for the hint indeed!

Comment: @granier The Sparx discussion got some feedback and I updated my edit above.

Comment: @Killian, great and thanks for the information, i do not follow sparx forum.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Assuming "final" in this case is the term java uses to define a constant, you can show that simply by using all caps as you have it, can you not?

Comment: @granier That would be a Java convention then, not an UML one.

Comment: @Kilian, it was not my remark ... about java caps, i would never do a such remark ... :)

Comment: @granier Oops ;-)

Comment: @BobRodes See my comment 2 above (addressed wrongly).

Comment: @ThomasKilian Sorry, my question wasn't at all clear. The use of "final" to mean a constant is a peculiarity of java syntax. However, it is indeed a UML convention to use all caps to denote a constant, although I don't find evidence that it is a universally accepted or official one. That given, might it be said that creating a <<final>> stereotype is unnecessary? Or why not?

Comment: @BobRodes That convention comes from C-times but it is not a UML specification. However, there's a `isConst` property in UML which could be used instead. I'll make an update to the answer.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Interesting. Yeah, I know that the convention isn't specifically a UML one. Thanks!